# Vue-Router: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

Please review my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 home_feed">
      <post-detail :posts="posts"></post-detail>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    async asyncData (params) {
      let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + this.$route.params.id + '/')
      return {
        posts: data
      }
    },
    components: {
      'post-detail': Item
    }
  }
</script>
```

I got this error: `Cannot read property '$route' of undefined` when I asyncdata from params.id, but when I type: console.log(this.$route.params.id), it goes right. How can I fix this

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this)` inside your export? I'm pretty sure you will need vue instance to access the route

Comment: I'm guessing you can't access `this` inside `asyncData`. By the looks of the `nuxt` documentation (I've never used it) you need to pass in a context to get a route param: `asyncData({params, context})` then you can access it as: `context.params.id`.

Comment: @craig_h Can I write API in an other ways instead of asyncData to get data?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to load data from server (from browser) in mounted lifecycle try this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.asyncData();
  },

  methods: {
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
     let { data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + this.$route.params.id + '/')
     this.data = data
   }
  }
}
```

Response from server will be available in `response` variable.

For `SSR` you can do :

```
async asyncData ({ store, route }) { 
  let { data} = await axios.get('localhost:8000/api/v1/users/'; + route.params.id + '/') 
  return {
    posts: data
  }
}
```

`asyncData` will be called before the components are instantiated, and it doesn't have access to `this`. (see https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/data.html *Logic Collocation with Components* for details)

Comment: Response return undefine, bro!!

Comment: in this case? in this code `asyncData` is placed in `methods` and must have this.$route

Comment: oh sorry, i changed `data` to `response`. I correct it back. try this ;)

Comment: It works perfectly. Vote for your answer. Thank you very much. @Mikhail :)

Comment: But is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Actually i was wrong, probably you are using ssr, and you can pass route as a part of an argument to `asyncData`. I editited answer for this case.

Comment: Please check my answer next. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For SSR you can  change

```
  <script>
    async asyncData ({ store, route }) { 
     let { data} = await axios.get('localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + this.$route.params.id + '/') 
     return {
      posts: data
     }
    }
  </script>
```

to

```
  <script>
    async asyncData ({ route }) { 
     let { data} = await axios.get('localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + route.params.id + '/') 
     return {
      posts: data
     }
    }
  </script>
```

According to the nuxt tutorial you can not have access to **this** inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component. [Nuxt Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#the-asyncdata-method)

Answer (score 0):

@Mikhail
This code is success:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.asyncData();
  },

  methods: {
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
     let { data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + route.params.id + '/')
     this.data = data
   }
  }
}
```

But when get API parent-children data like this: `{{data.user.username}}`, **data.user goes undefined**. So API data goes error.

I use Nuxt and your code for SSR not work:
**Error: Cannot read property $route of undefined**

```
<script>
async asyncData ({ store, route }) { 
  let { data} = await axios.get('localhost:8000/api/v1/users/'; + this.$route.params.id + '/') 
  return {
    posts: data
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to change `this.$route` to `route` inside `asyncData` and tell me what happened please

Comment: vue.runtime.esm.js:472 [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

Comment: so, it's warning about ssr problem, not about `route`. Now does axios work correctly (`data` contains real data from server)? Do you have this project on github? can you give a link on its, for search ssr problem?

Comment: Fixed: async asyncData ({ route }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/' + route.params.username + '/')
    return {
      users: data
    }
  },